# Call First Object in an array and loop it to match another array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have two NSMutablearrays of UIImages that go on top of each other. My code works perfectly when there are an even amount of images in both arrays. However, I am getting an out of bounds error when they are not equal.

What I am trying to do is basically take the first object of the overlayImg array and "duplicate" it to match the number of the other array. Here's what I got so far.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
 _overlayImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (self.record.imagebackground) {
 NSArray *array = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.record.imagebackground] mutableCopy];
 for(UIImage* image1 in array) {
 NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1)];
 [_overlayImg addObject:imageData1];

 }


-(void)final
for (int i = 0; i < self.arrSlidshowImg.count; i++)
        {
        if (self.arrSlidshowImg.count == _overlayImg.count)
            {
              _arrayImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_overlayImg objectAtIndex:i]];
             _flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
            [self makedesignWithImageData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i] andWatermarkData:[_gifoverlayImg objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            else

            {
             _arrayImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_overlayImg objectAtIndex:i]];
            _flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
                 [self makedesignWithImageData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i] andWatermarkData:[_overlayImg firstObject]];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do but if what you are trying to do in the final method is to fill up any empty space in the arrSlideshowImg then the count comparison that you are doing is just to make sure there are the same number of items in both arrays. What you should be doing is comparing the index i. Also don't access _overlayImg if there i is more than whats in the array. That's what's probably giving you the out of bounds error. Try something like this:

```
-(void)final
for (int i = 0; i < self.arrSlidshowImg.count; i++)
        {
        if (i < _overlayImg.count)
            {
              _arrayImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_overlayImg objectAtIndex:i]];
             _flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
            [self makedesignWithImageData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i] andWatermarkData:[_gifoverlayImg objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            else

            {
                 [self makedesignWithImageData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i] andWatermarkData:[_overlayImg firstObject]];
            }

        }
```